# JUnit test from commandline

Tags: java, command-line, junit

I am trying to run a JUnit 4 test from commandline. This is my current command:

```
java -cp C:\Users\some\.m2\repository\junit\junit\4.11\junit-4.11.jar junit.textui.TestRunner C:\Some\Path\target\test-classes\com\wicket\range\ui\MyTest.class
```

This gives a class not found error.

I have also tried the following:

```
C:\Some\Path\target\test-classes>java -cp C:\Users\some\.m2\repository\junit\junit\4.11\junit-4.11.jar junit.textui.TestRunner com.wicket.range.MyTest.class
```

This also gives a class not found error; what could be the issue here?

Comment: Include the stacktrace. It obviously means your classpath isn't right or is incomplete.

Comment: Class not found *.MyTestClass

Answer (score 2):

I assume your test class is under C:\Some\Path\target\test-classes (in appropriate subdirectory).  Your command has only junit in it. It also need class path to the test and other dependencies.

Try

```
java -cp C:\Some\Path\target\test-classes;C:\Users\some\.m2\repository\junit\junit\4.11\junit-4.11.jar junit.textui.TestRunner com.wicket.range.MyTest.class
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using Maven (saw the ".m2" in your classpath). How about this..

```
cd <location of pom.xml>
mvn -Dtest=MyTest test
```

Granted it may be a while until before it runs your test and it's not going to use JUnit's text ui runner, but it should run your test without much fuss about ClassNotFoundException. Examine files in target\surefire-reports for test results afterwards. Guess it depends on exactly what your goal is.

Otherwise, Jayan's answer looks about right to me. For his to work, I think you want to first

```
cd C:\Some\Path\target\test-classes
```